# Pattern-based optimizations on lambda calculus

Tags: optimization, functional-programming, computer-science, lambda-calculus

I am writing an interpreter for the lambda calculus in C#. So far I have gone down the following avenues for interpretation.

1. Compilation of terms to MSIL, such that lazy evaluation is still preserved.
2. Evaluation on a tree of terms (term rewriting).

At this moment, the MSIL compilation strategy is well over an order of magnitude faster in most any case I have been able to test. However, I am looking into optimizing the term rewriter by identifying patterns often used in the construction of LC terms. So far, I have come up with one method in particular which provides a relatively small speedup: identification of exponentiated applications. E.g. `f (f (f (f x)))` is simplified to `f^4 x`. Then, a rule for applications of equal applicant exponentials is used, namely `f^m (f^n x) = f^(m + n) x`. This rule works very well in particular for the exponentiation of church numerals.

This optimization has me wondering: Are there other pattern-based approaches to optimization in LC?

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-transformation-based-optimiser-for-haskell) will help? Also maybe you can apply [fusion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion), but iirc that needs specific rules.

Comment: This question is good, but I fear it is a bit too broad for StackOverflow.